# Sending string as an attachment using javamail gets duplicated content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm struggling to send a csv file over javamail.

Since the content is small, I constructed manually the data as CSV format, stored in memory and passed as `ByteArrayDataSource` to `MimeMessageHelper`. However, the received file has strangely double the content.

[image: Double content]

The code is pretty standard:

```java
// mail sender
try {
            MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true, "UTF-8");
            helper.setSubject(mailObj.getMailSubject());
            helper.setFrom(mailObj.getMailFrom());
            helper.setTo(mailObj.getMailTo());
            Mail.Attachment attachment = mailObj.getAttachment();
            if (attachment != null) helper.addAttachment(attachment.getFilename(),
                                                         attachment.getDataSource());
            javaMailSender.send(helper.getMimeMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot send email " + mailObj.toString(), e);
        }
```

```java
DataSource createDataSource(Data originalData) throws IOException {
        try (StringWriter out = new StringWriter(); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out) {
            @Override
            public void println() {
                write(LINE_SEP);
            }
        }) {
            pw.write('\uFEFF'); // Write BOM
            pw.println(HEADERS);
            for (AppointmentBookingEvent details : appointments) {
                // Concatenate the data with PrintWriter.println(...);
            }
            return new ByteArrayDataSource(out.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "text/csv");
        }
    }
```

I noticed that the method `DataSource.getInputStream()` is called twice by the sender's internal functions. Was that by any chance the cause ?

Comment: I has tried to write to a temp file then sent as `FileDataSource` but the duplication persists, though the temp file was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem came from `MimeMessageHelper`. I could not figure exactly where but the problem has gone when I explicitly constructed the body parts of mail.

```java
            MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            mail.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailObj.getMailFrom()));
            mail.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mailObj.getMailTo()));
            mail.setSubject(mailObj.getMailSubject());
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(getContentFromTemplate(mailObj.getModel(), mailObj.getLang(), mailObj.getTemplateName()), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            Mail.Attachment attachment = mailObj.getAttachment();
            if (attachment != null) {
                BodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(attachment.getFilename());
                attachmentBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
                attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attachment.getDataSource()));
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
            }
            mail.setContent(multipart);
            javaMailSender.send(mail);
```